# why "undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category" even if I do link against boost_system

Tags: gcc, boost, linker

I would understand this error message if I had not put the `-lboost_system` flag, but it is really here:

```
g++ -o build/myproject build/main/main.o -L/usr/local/boost/boost_1_52_0/boost/libs -L/usr/lib -Lbuild -L. -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread -lboost_regex -lpq -lmylibrary
build/libmylibrary.a(library.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
library.cpp:(.text+0x25f): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
library.cpp:(.text+0x269): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
library.cpp:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

Do you have any idea what should I investigate to solve the problem ? (I use gcc 4.6.3)

Comment: try putting it at the end.

Comment: nooo !? **that works ! ! !** do you have any idea why ?

Comment: It's explained in the second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/492498/1252091).

Comment: Even easier, `-DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED` likely makes it unnecessary to link with boost_system at all (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30877725/1918193).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Still complains:/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:278: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::hiden::sleep_until(timespec const&)'

Comment: @AlwaysLearning That's different, I was only talking about the symbols generic_category and system_category. You on the other hand need `-lboost_thread`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The order at which you link your libraries matters, in your case you have `library.cpp` that apparently uses the `boost_system` library

```
library.cpp:(.text+0x25f): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
library.cpp:(.text+0x269): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
library.cpp:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

To solve this you should move the boost_system library to the end of your link line

```
g++ -o build/myproject build/main/main.o -L/usr/local/boost/boost_1_52_0/boost/libs -L/usr/lib -Lbuild -L. -lboost_thread -lpthread -lboost_regex -lpq -lmylibrary **-lboost_system**
```

Alternatively, build `libmylibrary.so` as a shared library and link to the `boost_system` library directly.

Comment: Saved two lives! (at least)

Comment: With boost 1.65.0, I was linking `system` before `filesystem`, and it worked well. With boost 1.68.0 I had to reverse the order. Note that the two lins were not compiled with the exact same script/jam files. Apparently, they can change the fact that `system` should be linked last or first...